# Crystal report: changing command's data source

Tags: view, crystal-reports

I have to change the data source in quite a few reports. Its easy when the original data source uses table, but its more complicated when instead has a SQL command (well, practically its a view but made in the report, not in the original database).

Lets say that report has originally such command:

```
SELECT nbr FROM equipment WHERE equipment.owner='ABC'
```

I know that in the new database Equipment.nbr is called now Items.ID, so I can easily map this. But what about the rest of command, the "WHERE" part? In the new database there is obviously no Equipment.owner and possibly might not even be Items.owner. Does crystal simply drop this part? I know how to remake it, by simply adding selection formula to the report, but first I have to be know what happened to the "WHERE" condition, and after such mapping I can't anymore preview the SQL command in the data source.

Answer (score 1):

Confrim me where you are using this query.

1. If it is in Data soruce then no issue this report will work.
2. If it is in formula then I have doubt crystal report won't accept this format even in basic syntax mode.

Comment: Yes, it was in data source. It was working fine, but at the end I've decided to remake it instead remapping. Better safe than sorry.